# Does steady_clock::now return seconds?

Tags: c++11

I am trying to figure out what the value of t is ? Is it seconds or milliseconds ? The [steady_clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock/now/) reference does not mention the unit used.

```
 auto t = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() / 1000;
 auto p = t/1000;
```

I am thinking `now()` returns seconds and t is in milliseconds and p is in microseconds. Let me know if I am getting this right ?

Comment: If `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` returns seconds and you *divide* it by 1'000 surely you won’t get milliseconds?! For that you would have to *multiply* by 1'000.

Answer (score 3):

Unit of value returned by [std::chrono::steady_clock::now()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now) is not defined by standard (it is general value of type [std::chrono::time_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)).

The resolution of the std::chrono::time_point (it stores a value of type Duration indicating the time interval from the start of the Clock's epoch) is implementation dependent (platforms/compiler), and you shouldn't rely on it.

To get a desired unit, you can easily convert the time_point to a value in seconds, milliseconds, etc. by [duration casting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast):

```
auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

([time_since_epoch()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch) returns a duration representing the amount of time between *this and the clock's epoch).

Answer (score 2):

It's [`std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) (the documentation [on CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now) is generally better quality).

Guessing your next question — to convert from that to seconds you would use [`time_since_epoch()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch) (the documentation has an example of extracting a dimension-free number of seconds from it), or alternatively as `(now - epoch) / 1_second`